# accessing multiple kinect in ros groovy

Tags: ros, kinect, multiple, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

recently I was tasked with accessing multiple kinect in ros groovy ubuntu 12.04 in my lab, i just connect one kinect to my pc , and come across many problems during connecting 2 kinect to my pc ,and I have modified the launch file sevral times ,but failed .thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196390/accessing-multiple-kinect-in-ros-groovy/) by [wlzlnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20645/wlzlnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-10-31**:
Without more details it will be impossible to help you. What problems are you having? What launch file did you modify? How did you modify it? Please edit your original question to add more details.

**Comment by [wlzlnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20645/wlzlnu/) on 2014-11-01**:
I find some answers http://answers.ros.org/question/96071/accessing-multiple-kinects-in-ros-hydro/   . and then two kinects works  but  two kinects just show the rgb image  or just show the depth image  .they cant show the rgb and depth image at the same time  .thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the problem has been solved successfully.its my pc's problem.I changed a pc.and then it works well.

---

Originally posted by [wlzlnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20645/wlzlnu/) with karma: 26 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1